# Error Stackoverflow in android studio?

Tags: android, listview, sqlite, assets

I want to make a application that show text from db file to listview but it 
  shows error

These classes of my application

```
package com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    /**
     * Created by dell on 4/2/2017.
     */

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        String DB_PATH = null;
        private static String DB_NAME = "lib.db";
        private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
        private final Context myContext;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            myContext = context;
            this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
            Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
        }

        public void createDatabase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {

            } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDatabase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error Copying Database");
                }
            }

        }


        private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
            InputStream is;
            is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[10];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            is.close();
 }
private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
            if (checkDb != null) {
                checkDb.close();
            }
            return checkDb != null ? true : false;
        }
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (myDatabase != null) {
                myDatabase.close();
            }
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                try {
                    copyDatabase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public Cursor query(String table, String []columns, String selections, String []selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){

            return query(table,columns,selections,selectionArgs,groupBy,having,orderBy);
        }

        public Cursor query(String sql){
            return query(sql);
        }


    }
```

MainActivity is Here:

```
package com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.constantsToUse.UsefulConstants;
import com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private Cursor cousor;
    String SQl="SELECT Topic FROM TopicTable";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        copyDatabase();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                switch (itemValue){

                    case "Education":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=01;
                        SQl="SELECT Educational_Field FROM Education";
                        break;

                    case "Story":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=02;
                        break;


                    case "Health":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=03;
                        break;

                    case "Competitive":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=11;
                        break;

                    case "Commerce":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=12;
                        break;

                    case "Biology":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=13;
                        break;

                    case "Art":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=14;
                        break;

                    case "Technical ":
                        UsefulConstants.tableConstant=15;
                        SQl="SELECT Technologies FROM Technical";
                        break;



                }




                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });

    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
    DatabaseHelper myDb= new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        myDb.createDatabase();
        UsefulConstants.databaseHelper=myDb;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Unable to Create Database");
    }
    try {
        myDb.openDatabase();
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        throw e;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showListView();

}

    private void showListView() {

        Cursor cursor=UsefulConstants.databaseHelper.query(SQl);
        if (cursor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                data[i] = cursor.getString(0);
            }


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);


            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else if (cursor == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, Boolean.toString(cursor != null), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

It shows error :

```
 com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                  Process: com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo, PID: 12227
                                                                                                  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                      at com.example.dell.externalfilestoragedatabasedemo.database.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
                                                                                                    at com.examp
```

le.dell.externalfiles

Please help me to out of this

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this part of code:

```
public Cursor query(String table, String []columns, String selections, String []selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){
     return query(table,columns,selections,selectionArgs,groupBy,having,orderBy);
}
```

You return from `query` method the same method and you have infinite recursion. You should return something else